# What does "SE" stand for in font name "Chalkboard SE"

Tags: macos, font

I'm looking at two fonts that come with macOS: *Chalkboard* and *Chalkboard SE*.  What does the "SE" stand for?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the two Font in Font Book and seeing nothing other then Chalkboard SE has a Light version of the Font, where Chalkboard only has Regular and Bold versions, I decided to look at the two fonts in a Hex Editor. I noticed they were copyrighted six months apart:

- Chalkboard, was copyrighted in 2003-04, by Apple Computer, Inc.
- Chalkboard SE, was copyrighted in 2003-10, by Apple Computer, Inc.

I'd imagine that Chalkboard SE was created after Chalkboard as a second edition.

So, I'd say **SE** stands for **S**econd **E**dition.

Update Note: Looking at the Get Info sheet, it shows the Copyright. I guess I should have looked there first.

Answer (score 0):

Chalkboard SE has a much wider language coverage than ordinary Chalkboard.  Besides Latin, it includes Cherokee, Greek, and Cyrillic scripts.  Perhaps the SE means "Special Edition".